# Open ports only on specific domains

Tags: dns, centos, port, firewall, iptables

I am looking for the right command to open ports only to specific domains. The domain and its subdomain, go to the same server (CentOS)

However, for security reasons, I only want to open the posts on specific subdomains.

On the other domains the ports should not be reachable, so the ftp port 21 should only be open on ftp.domain.com and not on e.g. ssh.domain.com or mysql.domain.com

So I want to block everything (exclude port 80 and 443) and only allow specific ports to specific domains.

example

- 21 on ftp.domain.com
- 22 on ssh.domain.com
- 3306 on mysql.domain.com

I know it should work with iptables, but unfortunately I have trouble finding the right command.

I have found this only but i will only accept incoming ports.
`iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m string --string "google.com" --algo bm -j ACCEPT`

Maybe you have a more elegant solution than iptables.

Comment: Don't think that will work at that level. Think you are describing content filtering. For http there are headers that provide things like hostname, but how would sshd for example know the hostname? A fancy physical firewall might be able to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: FWIW: sort of on topic... https://serverfault.com/questions/255055/dynamic-port-forwarding-based-on-hostname-or-originating-ip

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using some reverse proxy server. The proxy server can filter the desired traffic to the actual service.
So how it will work is -

1. Let all your request come to reverse proxy server. eg. HAPROXY or nginx (both work at Layer 4 and 7)
2. Put a rule for the hostname in the proxy server config.
3. Forward the desired traffic to the actual host.